# Installing Ratchet Library with zmq with composer

Tags: php, wamp, zeromq

I want to implement push notification in a project, a simple chat program.

I am installing Ratchet Library in local wamp with zmq with composer. here is following json which is using from http://socketo.me/docs/push

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyApp": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/Ratchet": "0.3.*",
        "react/zmq": "0.2.*"
    }
}
```

It was giving error

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for react/zmq 0.2.0 -> satisfiable by react/zmq[v0.2.
0].
    - react/zmq v0.2.0 requires ext-zmq * -> the requested PHP extension zmq is
missing from your system.
```

I have search a lot how to install zmq extension. Then i have installed zmq extansion. Checked in phpinfo

```
zmq

ZMQ extension   enabled
ZMQ extension version   1.1.2
libzmq version  2.2.0
```

But still when i installing composer from cmd giving me same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are using the Command line for things like Composer, you may need to make the same extension changes to the CLI version of the php.ini

By that I mean that when you are using the CLI ( Command Line Interface ) PHP loads a different php.ini it is found in the `\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z` folder and called php.ini.

So add the same `extension=????` and any others that you may require to this php.ini file and it should work.